# Convert [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsarray, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I need to convert my `[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]` to `NSArray`.

I've already tried before use `[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]` but it returns me a lot of properties from other Atributes that I don't need. I just want to get a list of values from a concrete attribute called `circuito` inside the entity `Autobus`.

Comment: Try `[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] valueForKey:@"circuito"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]` will return array of instances of the entity specified by the fetch request. Here `fetchedObjects` return array of `Autobus` entities. To get array of values from a concrete attribute called `circuito` do

```
[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] valueForKey:@"circuito"];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would clarify about used terminology. The *"lot of code"* that you received is not correct.

As per the documentation for `fetchedObjects` property:

> The results array only includes instances of the entity specified by
>   the fetch request (fetchRequest) and that match its predicate.
>   (If the fetch request has no predicate, then the results array includes all
>   instances of the entity specified by the fetch request)

---

In other words, you grab instances of your entity `Autobus`

So, in my opinion you should clarify

1. What is the *lot of code* you grab
2. Why you don't want the *lot of code*
3. What's your goal

For example:
If you need to display results in a table view you will make visible the only attributes you are interested in.
You won't grab the ones that are not useful for a specific user interface.